# How to turn a system of first order into a second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

So I have two equations

$X' = aX + bY$

$Y' = cX + dY$

I want to convert it back to a second order equation with the form

$X'' + \alpha X' + \beta X$ with $\alpha,\beta$ in terms of a,b,c,d.

I have been racking my brain for hours trying to go backwards from a reduction of order, but just can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure this is what you're looking for, but couldn't you take the derivative of the first equation, then substitute $Y$ and $Y^\prime$ in?

Comment: Nonlinear version of question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175641/can-you-convert-a-system-of-coupled-first-order-des-into-a-higher-order-de

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you derive the first equation, you get: 
$$  X ^"=aX '+bY ' $$ 
(if you are considering $a$ and $b$ as constants).
But we have $Y'=cX+dY $, so substitute in the above equation, you get 
$$ X ^" = a X' +b(cX+dY).$$
Note that $Y=\frac{1}{b}(X'-aX)$ for $b \neq 0$.
So, substituting again you get the final answer.

Comment: ah, that was much easier than I was making it, just a question how did you get Y, I think that was where I was running into major issues.

Comment: Im guessing you just solve the first equation correct?

Comment: I get $Y$  from  the first equation $X'=aX+bY$.

Comment: Awesome that's what I thought thanks for the help! Storing that trick for later!