# Can you convert a system of coupled first order DEs into a higher order DE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know the reverse is possible (simply define every higher order derivative as a new variable) but is it always possible to take $n$ equations of the form

$\dot{x_1} = f_1(x_1, x_2, ... , x_n, t)$

$\dot{x_2} = f_2(x_1, x_2, ... , x_n, t)$

.

.

$\dot{x_n} = f_n(x_1, x_2, ... , x_n, t)$

Can we write a single $n^{th}$ order DE from this? I seem to remember that this is generally not possible but if so, can someone show a counter-example and a bit of intuiton for why not?

Comment: Consider $x'=2x+2y, y'=x-y$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider two coupled equations
$$(1)\quad x'=f(x,y,t),\qquad (2)\quad y'=g(x,y,t)\ .$$
Differentiating $(1)$ with respect to $t$ we obtain
$$(3)\quad x''=f_{.1}(x,y,t)x'+ f_{.2}(x,y,t)y'+f_{.3}(x,y,t)\ .$$
If it is algebraically possible to eliminate the variables $y$ and $y'$ from the three equations $(1)$–$(3)$ we obtain a single equation $F(x,x',x'',t)=0$ involving only the unknown function $t\mapsto x(t)$. In most cases it will not be possible to do this explicitly.

The example proposed by Chee Han however is tame: Eliminating $y$ and $y'$ from the three equations$$x'=2x+2y,\quad y'=x-y,\quad x''=2x'+2y'$$ results in 
$$x''=x'+4x\ .$$

Comment: Could you also add a counter-example where it is impossible to elminiate y and y' from the three equations? I'm struggling to see why a variable cannot be isolated and expressed in terms of the remaning. Is this only if the functions are non-invertible?